# what should i use try and catch block or onerror event

Tags: javascript, try-catch, onerror

I am new to javascript.Sometimes the error comes in the program but after reviewing it so many times the mistake is still unsolved.Tough the mistakes are too small to get in the sight .so to get away from this shall i use the event onError or the try catch block .Which will be the good practice for doing this .

Or is there is another way to find out the mistake or error in program in less time..

please let me know..

Comment: I assume you already [jslint-ed](http://www.jslint.com/) your javascript?

Comment: It depends on the type of error, can you show the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Personally I prefer try - catch

Comment: do you know about console.log?

Comment: for suppose in a code of 200 line i missed the spelling  of document instead of that i had written "documet".And after viewing it so many times this mistake could not get in to my sight ..this kind of mistakes i ma talking about.or some time operator error..

Comment: yes @Juno i know about  console.log.but not i detail only little part of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessarily good to say one is better than the other. For your situation, I do feel that `onerror` is easy and appropriate, as it lets you alert the error message reported by JavaScript without needing to rewrite your code within try/catch blocks.

Demo code with the `onerror` handler in a self-contained script added above the rest of the page's code, along with an example syntax error which triggers a prompt showing the JavaScript error message.

```
<script>
onerror = function(m) {
    return confirm(
        'Scripts on this page generated an error message: ' +
         m +
        '\n\nDo you wish to continue running the scripts?');
}
</script>

<script>
alert(' hello';
</script>
```

The above bad code generates an alert message 'unexpected token ;' because of the missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You friends are:

- Chrome's Developer Tools: All kinds of tools are packed together.

  - Open Developer Tools  by F12, Ctrl + Shift + I on Windows or Cmd + Opt + I on Mac
- console.log: debug at runtime.
- jshint: check syntax / misspelled variables / unused codes / unused variables / ... before run.

try / catch is very dangerous approach unless you do some logging inside catch because it will hide all errors, not fix them. Besides, it will make your code run slow.

Comment: whenever i use console.log in my code it does not do on browser any thing.so in place of that i use alert();

Comment: If you are using chrome (you should when you test your code), Open Developer Tools by F12, Ctrl + Shift + I on Windows or Cmd + Opt + I on Mac.

Comment: by your words("t will hide all errors, not fix them. ") what you want to point out.As far as i know  about try catch block if any errors come then it can be  viewed by the object.

Comment: yeah if you want to know about the error. use developers tools' console since it will let you see the latest code stacks that caused the error.

Comment: @juno..i troubled you a lot. one last Q ..how can i edit the code in developer tool